# are any files excluded from the Jar on build?

Tags: java, netbeans, build

I have a java source file located in src/com/example/myClass

I also have a javascript file located in the same folder.

```
private static final File jsScript = new File("src/com/example/myClass/controllerScript.js");
```

My project reads the contents of the js file and does this successfully in testing, i.e. running the file in the IDE.

but when i build and run my jar its as if the javascript is no longer included, have i to specifically include non java files? does the location of the file move or become relative when being built.

The only excluded options are "**/*.java,**/*.form"

I am running Net Beans an with anything other than standard clean/build dist for my jar, and i dont believe i had to do anything specific for images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is there, you can simply open up the jar in your favorite zip tool and see for yourself.

The problem is that little snippet of code you posted; you are opening the file as if it exists on your harddrive, while you should be opening it as a resource on the classpath because it is now -inside- your jar.

Try this from your MyClass code:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("controllerScript.js");
// read data as per usual, don't forget to close the input stream
```

This works specifically in MyClass because the controllerScript.js file is in the same package. Alternatively, this works from any class in your application's jar:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/example/myClass/controllerScript.js");
```

Comment: Thank you that worked ! as i was using it in a static context, i used myClass.class instead of getClass, thanks it gave me a much greater understanding of what was going on.